# UPDATE columns based on another table using the foreign key

Tags: sql-server, azure

Two tables `AVAIL_SCHEDULE` and `EMPLOYEE_SCHEDULE`. Managers insert hours to work in the `AVAIL_SCHEDULE` table. Employees look at the available hours and choose the times they would like to work (col Schedule_action: PICK).

A manager can also DELETE the entire schedule.

What I want to do is find the corresponding PICK employee schedule hours that have been affected by the DELETE.

For example:

Table:  `AVAIL_SCHEDULE`

[image]

Employee picked up 30 min shift from 7:00-7:30 on 5/01/2020. Then at a later time, a manager DELETED the shift. So, that entire 30 min shift on 5/1 is gone for ALL employee's who signed up. How can I query for all the PICK records that have a DELETE schedule_slot? (DELETE action would be 1 to many)

What I'm trying to do is UPDATE the employee_schedule table to show their altered schedule. The col. schedule_ID is a foreign key in employee_schedule table. Is this possible? The columns PROGR, DATE_INT, DATE_KEY, and SCHEDULE_SLOT are the same for DELETE and PICK actions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Adding data:

```
CREATE TABLE AVAIL_SCHEDULE
(
    [SCHEDULE_ID] [bigint]  NULL,
    [PROGRAM_NUMBER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DATE_INTERVAL] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DATETIME_KEY] [int] NULL,
    [ACTIVITY] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [COSMOS_SLOT_ID] [varchar](100) NULL
 )

 INSERT INTO AVAIL_SCHEDULE (SCHEDULE_ID, PROGRAM_NUMBER, DATE_INTERVAL, DATETIME_KEY, ACTIVITY, COSMOS_SLOT_ID)
 VALUES (174379, 3254, '2020-05-01 07:15:00', 502494, 'PICK', '2020-05-01_3254_0715_4'),
        (174381, 3254, '2020-05-01 07:00:00', 502493, 'PICK', '2020-05-01_3254_0700_4'),
        (175679, 3254, '2020-05-01 07:15:00', 502494, 'DELETE', '2020-05-01_3254_0715_4'),
        (175690, 3254, '2020-05-01 07:00:00', 502493, 'DELETE', '2020-05-01_3254_0700_4');
```

Comment: You need to show some sample data and expected results (using **formatted text**) because we can help you. Too hard to understand in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code might help you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ASCH.*
FROM AVAIL_SCHEDULE ASCH
     JOIN AVAIL_SCHEDULE ASCH2 ON ASCH.COSMOS_SLOT_ID = ASCH2.COSMOS_SLOT_ID
                                  AND ASCH.ACTIVITY = 'PICK'
                                  AND ASCH2.ACTIVITY = 'DELETE'
WHERE ASCH.ACTIVITY = 'PICK';
```

db<>fiddle **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe97e94a5230e05db7a2a933add7ccf1)**

Comment: Thank you sacse, that is exactly what I was looking for.  I think I was over analyzing the issue, so thank you for answer.  --breeze